# Lazarus: How to unbind from Network Interface?

Tags: sockets, networking, tcp, lazarus, unbind

I would like to know how you can unbind from Network Interface after disconnecting the socket.

For instance:

```
procedure Testing_TCPSocket;
var lsock:TTCPBlockSocket;
begin
    lsock := TTCPBlockSocket.Create;

    lsock.bind('192.168.1.33','1234');

    lsock.connect('192.168.1.44','4321');
    lsock.closesocket;

    //how do you unbind here
    lsock.unbind; //Maybe ????????????

    lsock.Free;
end;
```

I don't see any options for unbinding.
Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Once a socket is bound, it cannot be unbound manually.  The OS will unbind it when the socket is closed and freed.  A socket cannot be reused once it is closed, and you cannot keep using a closed socket for anything.  So this is not an issue you should be worrying about.  Close and free your socket and move on, let the OS deal with the binding in its own way.  This is especially important if SO_LINGER is enabled on the socket (which it is by default), which allows the OS to keep the socket open in the background for a few moments so it can remove any lingering data for that socket from the network.

Comment: +1 but (1) SO_LINGER is disabled by default, see the man page, and (2) you're mixing up SO_LINGER with the TIME_WAIT state. If enabled, SO_LINGER *blocks the close() method while the output drains,* not while the system 'removes lingering data from the network'. Otherwise close is asynchronous, but output draining still happens. There is a third option but let's not talk about it.

Comment: Remy, I made a mistake. That was just an example. Thanks for the information....let me go ahead and apply the changes. I will let you know of my result soon. Thanks.

Comment: It would seem SO_LINGER operates differently on different OSes. What I described is how it works on Windows. Disabling SO_LINGER can avoid the TIME_WAIT state, and having SO_LINGER enabled can be set to not block `closesocket()` from exiting so the drain can be done in background and the app can move on to other things (this is the default behavior).

Comment: @RemyLebeau No. That's not how it works on Windows. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737582%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). It operates the same on all OSes. Setting it to `true` with a positive timeout value blocks the close for up to the timeout while the output drains. The default is `false,` and *this* setting means the close is asynchronous but draining still happens, and ditto `TIME_WAIT.` The third option I mentioned causes a reset instead of an orderly close (RST instead of FIN), and therefore no `TIME_WAIT.` You're still confusing SO_LINGER and TIME_WAIT.